# Split long string into smaller pieces in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm trying to solve Project Euler's problem with scala [Large sum problem](http://projecteuler.net/problem=13), but failing to find a way how can I split one big string into hundred 50 character long pieces. Of course I could use some kind of foreach loop and do it old imperative style, but there has to be a functional way also. Ideally the result would be a list of 100 strings.

Comment: Use `string.split("\n")` is better

Comment: This would only work if there is "\n" after each 50 characters

Comment: ... which there is, assuming you're copy/pasting the list of numbers into your source file. If you're reading from a file, you don't need to split it because it's already an Iterator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
val chunkLen = 3
"abcdefg".grouped(chunkLen).toList
// List(abc, def, g)
```

Of course, toList isn't necessary if you want iterative processing

Answer (score 0):

use String.substring and java.math.BigInteger